# Eliminar headers de una respuesta ether.tcpReply

Tags: arduino

Estoy manejando un modulo Ethernet (**enc28j60**) para Arduino con la libreria **EtherCard**. Estoy enviando una consulta POST a un servidor web, y necesito saber la respuesta del servidor.
Mi tcpReply regresa este resultado:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 06:03:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.9
Content-Length: 7
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

success
```

Y solamente necesito lo que devuelve el servidor. Nota que no siempre es success, podria ser incluso errores que suceden en MySQL.

Intente con lo siguiente:

```
    String build = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(reply) - 189; i++) build += reply[215 + i];
    Serial.print(build);
    if(build == "success")
        Serial.println("Yes :)");
    else if(build == "no")
        Serial.println("No :C");
    else
    {
        Serial.print("Unknown? ");
        Serial.println(build);
    }
```

Pero solamente funciona si el texto es "success". Si es cualquier otro de distinta longitud, no filtra correctamente el resultado.

Dejo mi codigo completo aqui:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>
byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };
const char website[] PROGMEM = "192.168.1.64";
byte Ethernet::buffer[700];

uint32_t timer;
Stash stash;
static byte session_id;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0) 
    Serial.println( "Controlador no iniciado.");
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
    Serial.println("Error al crear la IP");

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
}

void SendPost(String post){
  byte sd = stash.create();
  stash.print("key=123&");
  stash.print(post);
  stash.save();

  Stash::prepare(PSTR("POST http://$F/$F HTTP/1.0" "\r\n"
              "Host: $F" "\r\n"
              "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n"
              "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n"
              "\r\n"
              "$H"),
  website, PSTR("run.php"), website, stash.size(), sd);
  session_id = ether.tcpSend();
}

bool sent = false;

void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  const char* reply = ether.tcpReply(session_id);

  if (millis() > timer && reply == 0 && !sent) {
    timer = millis() + 1000;
    SendPost("type=setstatus&device=1&val=1");
  }
  else if(reply != 0){
    sent = true;

    String build = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(reply) - 189; i++) build += reply[215 + i];
    Serial.print(build);
    if(build == "success")
        Serial.println("Yes :)");
    else if(build == "no")
        Serial.println("No :C");
    else
    {
        Serial.print("Unknown? ");
        Serial.println(build);
    }

  }
}
```

Aprecio la ayuda, dedique horas de busqueda pero no logro encontrar la solucion.

Comment: Los headers están separados del cuerpo de la función por una línea vacía. Si lees la respuesta y descartas todo hasta la línea vacía inclusive, estaras al comienzo del cuerpo de la respuesta.

Comment: @CandidMoe Si pense acerca de eso, pero lamentablemente desconozco como lograr esto en C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solucion, segui la idea de eliminar todas las lineas que contengan un \n, y dejar la respuesta al final.

```
const char* reply = ether.tcpReply(session_id);
int lines = 0;
const char *p = &reply[0];
for(int i = 0; i < reply.length(); i++){
    if(p[i] == '\n')
        lines++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    reply.erase(0, reply.find("\n") + 1);
}

switch(reply){
        case "success":
        break;
        default:
        break;
}
```

[Ejemplo sencillo aqui](https://onlinegdb.com/BJFnwe4dw)